# Perl Regular expression to insert string at specific places

Tags: regex, string, perl, insert

**I have the following piece of code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw( HELLO );

while (<DATA>) {
chomp;
my $url = URI->new($_);
my $path = $url->path();

for (@insert_words) {
  # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
  my $insert_word = $_;
  local our @paths;
  $path =~ m{
     ^(.*/)([^/]*)((?:/.*)?)\z
     (?{

        push @paths, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
        if (length($2)) {
           push @paths, "$1$insert_word$3";
           push @paths, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
        }
     })
     (?!)
  }x;

  for (@paths) {
     $url->path($_);
     print "$url\n";
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=checkout/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
```

At the moment the above piece of code works perfectly for the `stackoverflow and superuser` urls in `__DATA__`. It gives the following output for the `stackoverflow` url:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLOrabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLOdog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLO/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/
```

As you can see it inserts the string `HELLO` at specific places when it comes across a slash (/).

**The problem I am having:**

I want the same thing to happen when an equals sign (=) is found in the url.

Using `http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=checkout` as an example, I want the output to give me the following:

```
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=HELLOcheckout/   <- puts HELLO before the string after the equals
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=HELLO/   <- replaces the string after the equals with HELLO
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=checkoutHELLO/  <- puts HELLO after the string that is after the equals
```

I thought that changing the regular expression from

`^(.*/)([^/]*)((?:/.*)?)\z`

to

`^(.*[/=])([^/=]*)((?:[/=].*)?)\z` would work but it does not.

**What would I need to change to the regular expression to make it do this?**

Your help is much appreciated, many thanks

__UPDATE_*_*_

It needs to be able to handle multiple parameters, for example if I had the url `http://www.example.com/dog/cat=2&foo=5` the output I should get is as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/HELLOdog/cat=2&foo=5  
http://www.example.com/HELLO/cat=2&foo=5
http://www.example.com/dogHELLO/cat=2&foo=5
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=HELLO2&foo=5
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=HELLO&foo=5
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=2HELLO&foo=5
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=2&foo=HELLO5
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=2&foo=HELLO
http://www.example.com/dog/cat=2&foo=5HELLO
```

The code I already have works correctly and **does this for every slash it comes across** in the url, but I **now want it to do it when it comes across an `=` in the url as well** (or any other character I choose to specify in the regex e.g [/=@-]).

Comment: `local our $insert_word`? What is that supposed to do different than `my $insert_word`?

Comment: @TLP - your correct, there is no reason why I cant use `my $insert_word` instead, thanks. I think at some point I must have accidentally copied the `local our` from the line below. Edited the code in my question.

Comment: What if you have multiple parameters? (`?route=checkout&foo=bar&baz=sproing`).  Do you need to handle that, too, and if so, how?

Comment: @dan1111 - I have added an update at the bottom of my question to answer your question, let me know if it is still not clear. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the regex engine to work to perform the backtracking for you is a clever technique.

The main problem is the part after a question mark is the *query*, available through `$url->query`. `$url->path` returns the path component without the query.

Modifying your code to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw( HELLO );

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $url = URI->new($_);
    my $path = $url->path();
    my $query = $url->query;

    for (@insert_words) {
      # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
      my $insert_word = $_;
      local our @paths;
      $path =~ m{
         ^(.*/)([^/]*)((?:/.*)?)\z
         (?{
            push @paths, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
            if (length($2)) {
               push @paths, "$1$insert_word$3";
               push @paths, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
            }
         })
         (?!)
      }x;

      local our @queries;
      if (defined $query) {
          $query =~ m{
              ^(.*[/=])([^/=&]*)((?:[/=&].*)?)\z
              (?{
                  if (length $2) {
                      push @queries, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
                      push @queries, "$1$insert_word$3";
                      push @queries, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
                  }
              })
              (?!)
          }x;
      }

      for (@paths) {
          $url->path($_);

          if (@queries) {
              for (@queries) {
                  $url->query($_);
                  print $url, "\n";
              }
          }
          else {
              print $url, "\n";
          }
      }
    }
}

__DATA__
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.php?route=checkout/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7/
```

gives the following output. The logic for query replacements is slightly different because it would append each `@insert_words` after the trailing slash in the query, if present.

```
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLOindex.php?route=HELLOcheckout/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLOindex.php?route=HELLO/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLOindex.php?route=checkoutHELLO/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLO?route=HELLOcheckout/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLO?route=HELLO/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/HELLO?route=checkoutHELLO/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.phpHELLO?route=HELLOcheckout/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.phpHELLO?route=HELLO/
http://www.bagandboxfactory.com/index.phpHELLO?route=checkoutHELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLOrabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLOdog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLO/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/HELLO
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLOhamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamsterHELLO/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/HELLOrabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/HELLO/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/HELLO/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/HELLOdog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/HELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=9&other=HELLO7/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=9&other=HELLO/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=9&other=7HELLO/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=HELLO9&other=7/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=HELLO&other=7/
http://www.example.com/HELLOindex.php?route=9HELLO&other=7/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=9&other=HELLO7/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=9&other=HELLO/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=9&other=7HELLO/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=HELLO9&other=7/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=HELLO&other=7/
http://www.example.com/HELLO?route=9HELLO&other=7/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=9&other=HELLO7/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=9&other=HELLO/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=9&other=7HELLO/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=HELLO9&other=7/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=HELLO&other=7/
http://www.example.com/index.phpHELLO?route=9HELLO&other=7/
```

Comment: thats excellent and exactly what I was looking for, thankyou. I wasn't aware of `$url->query` so that will make my life a whole lot easier. It means I can actually forget about the `$url->path` part as it is only the query part I am really interested in. The issue I have now is when there are multiple parameters for example `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7/`. It appears that it is seeing `9&other` as the parameter rather than just the `9` so it is putting the `HELLO` in incorrectly. What would I need to change to stop this from happening? thanks for your help

Comment: @perl-user You would need to treat `&` as a separator too. See updated answer, which assumes that all HTML entities (*e.g.*, `&amp;`) have already been decoded.

Comment: I thought that was the correct thing to do, but as the `&` is now seen as a separator it has the unwanted side effect of doing this as well: `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&HELLOother=7/` `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&HELLO=7/` `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&otherHELLO=7/`. What would have to be done to also prevent this from occurring as a result? , thanks for your help

Comment: I managed to do what I was having problems with (described in the comment above) by altering the first part of the `$query` regular expression to `(.*[/=])` rather than `(.*[/=&])`. Thanks for your help, much appreciated